# Which 3D movie file format is automatically recognized as 3D by the PS3?

Tags: ps3

I just bought a 3D TV. With 3D blu-rays and 3D games, the PS3 tells the TV that the following thing is 3D and the TV automatically switches to 3D mode.

I have a few 3D shorts in mp4 files (side-by-side). When I play them, they show up side-by-side and I have to tell my TV manually that this is 3D.

I would like to convert those shorts to a different format, so that when I start them up, the PS3 would automatically recognize that this format is a 3D format, tell it to the TV which would then automatically switch to 3D mode.

1. Is this possible?
2. What file format do I need to convert my stuff to?
3. Any hints which software could do this on OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PS3 will automatically recognize 3D Frame Sequential H264 video streams in MP4 files that conform to the MSNV brand specifications and have the necessary 3D flags.

Here is a guide that will help you create such files:
http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=170863

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is possible, but I haven't tested it exhaustively.  There are [several](http://www.mkvconvertersoft.com/mac-mkv-converter/) [video](http://www.video-converter-mac.org/video-converter-ultimate-mac/) [converter](http://www.imtoo.com/video-converter-mac.html) tools around that say they can make PS3 compatible 3D movie files, you might try a few and see if the PS3 recognizes them.  Each of those tools appears to have a free trial that you can download to see if it works for you, and then you can pick one if the price is right.

I think it should probably also be possible to do this with [Handbrake](https://forum.handbrake.fr/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=16217&hilit=ps3), although their PS3 thread doesn't seem to mention 3D.  At the very least, it's something to keep an eye on.

I'd try some variant of MPEG-4 if one is available (and supported by the PS3), as that appears to be the [only file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video) that supports 3D extensions natively.

3D television is still in its infancy, so standards haven't exactly been firmed up for file formats and such.  I'd weigh the amount of time you're going to invest in trying various file formats/conversion programs against the annoyance of pressing the "manual 3D mode" button on your TV to see if it's worth pursuing past a certain point.

Comment: I so far found out that the .mpo image format (Multi Picture Object) makes this switch automatically. Not working are the jps and pns image formats. But my question was about the video side, and when it comes to video, MTS and MPEG4-MVC are viable 3D formats, but they are not recognized properly by the PS3. If somebody else has more insight, I'd still love to hear more info. Thanks

Comment: Update: I found a video that automatically tells the PS3 it's in 3D. Here it is:
https://rapidshare.com/files/2022363599/Uncharted3_3DTrailer_720p.MP4

Steps to reproduce: On your USB flash drive, create a root directory called "VIDEO". Copy this file into it. Plug it into PS3. Start your PS3, navigate to Video, flash drive, start the video, PS3 will prompt you that it detected a 3D movie :-)

When played on a PC, this video shows up as 60fps. So far, I wasn't able to find any 3D flags. Maybe somebody who knows the file structure of an MP4 file could help along here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just downloaded the video and played it on my PS3. I also did some research, it's an .mp4 file that is encoded using AVCHD 2.0 which is playable in both 2D and 3D. It's a format used by some 3D HD cameras. If played back on the flashdrive on your PS3, it will only play in 2D. Copy it to the systems harddrive and it prompt you that it detected a 3D movie.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your PS3 could not automatically recognize the 3D format may be it is not the original format it set. You need a 3D converter that can rip to 3D effect.  The 3D effect is including side-by-side, top/buttom and arapghy.

I know Pavtbe can make it possible that you can download the free version and see which 3D format can be recognized by your PS3 automatically.It also support Windows version as well as Mac version